# How to Triple Boot Windows 10 Windows 10 Insider and Ubuntu?

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, windows-10

So I am wondering how do I triple boot Windows 10, Windows 10 Insider Preview, and Ubuntu. Is this even possible?

*Note that I already have Windows 10 and Ubuntu installed. ***I will be installing Windows 10 Insider Preview***

Comment: Yes, it's possible but not recommend. Windows 10 has been known to automatically erase people's Linux partitions during big updates, and the insider preview will be updating itself regularly...

Comment: make separate partition for windows 10 insider preview and make bootbale pendrive and boot it in UEFI mode into that partiotion.

Comment: ...and what is the problem?

Comment: So what you guys are saying that it isn't possible or it is possible?

Comment: Possible, but you are warned that it might be a bumpy ride.

Comment: Sounds like it is safer to run it in a virtual pc so guess thats the route I am going to take

Thanks